# Final energy of a particle after an elastic collision at relativistic speed

Tags: special-relativity, collision

A particle with rest mass of $M$ of total energy $E$ collides with a stationary particle of mass $m$.  The collision is elastic.  How to show that the final energy $E'$ (defining $c=1$) of the particle with mass $M$ is given by the following expression?

$$E' = \frac{2mM^2+E(m^2+M^2)}{2Em+m^2+M^2}$$

Comment: How would you do it if it *weren't* relativistic?

Comment: @KyleKanos hmm... if it weren't relativistic, I'll create two equations, one for energy conservation and one for momentum conservation.  I've tried to do it with this case but the equations quickly cascaded into a very long equation (while this question is supposed to only take 6 mins at max).